# Can't achieve printing out results as expected in my for loops

Tags: python

My code gets some inputs and eventually print some results. I have associated with `a` meaning of `ice cream` or `shortcutA()` function, `/` meaning separation of the products and `everything else` as `unrecognized` for the moment. After that the user will be asked to input the amount for each product and will be printed out a sum of what he has input with some modification to the output printed.

```
sentences = str(input("please enter the password :"))

for i in sentences:
  if i == "/":
    howMuchOrder = input("please enter the order :")
  else:
    continue

class meaning():
  def shortcutA (self):
    global sentences
    print ("ice cream")
    for i in sentences:
        if i != "/":
          print ("sweet ice") 
        elif i =="/":
          print ('order is ' + str(int(howMuchOrder)))

def main():
    m = meaning()
    print_flag = False
    for i in sentences :
        if i in ['a', 'b', '/'] and not print_flag:
          print("your code is: ")
          print_flag = True
        if i == "a" :
          m.shortcutA()
        elif i == "/":
          break
        else :
             print ("unrecognized")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

> > > let say input is just word **a** then the outcome will be:
> > >       your code is: 
> > >       ice cream sweet ice
> > >
> > > let say input is just word **a/** then the outcome will be:
> > >       your code is: 
> > >       ice cream order is 20 sweet ice

if the input be **a/a/** , and order is 20 (for both), then desired outcome should be:

```
your code is: ice cream order is 20 sweet ice ice cream order is 20 sweet ice
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: There is too much wrong with this code and your desired output. howMuchOrder is of no use in for loop, it does not store all values, use list instead of a single value. Your shortcutA needs to be changed, specifically the if and elif in for loop need to be swtiched to get your output. And you cannot print `ice cream` again because you have only 1 instance of that method.

Comment: could you clarify what you want...i dont understant what you want exactly..for example if my input is a/xdfrettt////a/www  what is the output?

Comment: @Frenchy According to the code and the outcome @zazuvahe wrote `a` = ice cream product, `/` = separation of products, `everything else` is unrecognized. So the output for `a/xdfrettt////a/www` will be your `code is:`
`ice cream order is 20 sweet ice`
`unrecognized`
`ice cream order is 20 sweet ice`
`unrecognized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you treat:

- `a` shortcut as `ice cream`
- `whatever else` as an `unrecognized`

Then for the `shortcutA` you would like to print `ice cream order is <order_amount> sweet ice`

Based on those understanding and that given `a/a/` you expect `ice cream order is 20 sweet ice ice cream order is 20 sweet ice` I have modified a little bit of your logic and some part but not everything to show you how to achieve your desired output **(works in python 2.x, see in the end how to make it work in python 3.x)**:

```
# now input() works in same way on either python 2.x or 3.x
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

sentences = str(input("please enter the password :"))

# split sentences by '/', remove empty values, put result in a list
listOrderName = list(filter(None, sentences.split('/')))
totalOrder = sentences.count('/')
listOrderAmount = [0]*totalOrder

if totalOrder > 0:
    for index, i in enumerate(listOrderAmount):
        howMuchOrder = input("please enter the order :")
        listOrderAmount[index] = howMuchOrder

#Exmple of what are your two input
print(listOrderName) #can be deleted
print(listOrderAmount) #can be deleted

class meaning():
  def shortcutA (self, position):
    global listOrderAmount, totalOrder

    print("ice cream"),

    if totalOrder > 0:
        totalOrder = totalOrder - 1
        amount = listOrderAmount[position]
        print('order is ' + str(int(amount))),

    print("sweet ice")

  def shortcutUnrecognized(self):
    print("unrecognized")

def main():
    m = meaning()
    print_flag = False
    position = -1

    global listOrderName
    for order in listOrderName :
        position += 1
        if order in ['a', 'b'] and not print_flag:
          print("your code is: ")
          print_flag = True
        if order == "a" :
          m.shortcutA(position)
        else :
          m.shortcutUnrecognized()  


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

An example of usage:

```
#please enter the password :a/a/
#please enter the order :20
#please enter the order :20
#['a', 'a']
#['20', '20']
#your code is: 
#ice cream order is 20 sweet ice
#ice cream order is 20 sweet ice
```

Another example of usage:

```
#please enter the password :a/b
#please enter the order :20
#please enter the order :20
#['a', 'b']
#['20', '20']
#your code is: 
#ice cream order is 20 sweet ice
#unrecognized
```

Another example of usage:

```
#please enter the password :a/a
#please enter the order :20
#['a', 'a']
#['20']
#your code is: 
#ice cream order is 20 sweet ice
#ice cream sweet ice
```

You can remove the prints that are not useful to you (like `print(listOrderName)` and `print(listOrderAmount)`.

**python 2.x**
in `print("ice cream"),` for example, the `,` serves to not put an EOL (End of Line or New Line) after the print so we have some printing in the same line and some others in new lines. This works in `python 2.x`

**python 3.x**
To achieve the same behaviour as `print(..),` in `python 3.x` you can replace `print("ice cream"),` for example with `print("ice cream", end =" ")`. So in essence to make the script work in the same way for the printing part in python 3.x change this:

```
print("ice cream"),
print('order is ' + str(int(amount))),
```

into this:

```
print("ice cream", end =" ")
print('order is ' + str(int(amount)), end =" ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately this work for a/a/ but not "a" alone. I edited the post for better undestanding, but your code was helpful

Comment: Oh now I see your new updates to the question. I just updated the code in my answer, can you check? I guess now you are able to go alone with it and do any further modification to the code as you wish.

Comment: sry I coudn't check till now, yes it working thank you for helping a newbie